# (leeSM 2-4) show inclusion map $i: \overline{B}^n \hookrightarrow R^n$ is smooth, where $\overline{B}^n$ regarded as smooth manifold w/ boundary

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

i'm having trouble showing the smoothness condition for $p \in \partial B^n$.

my charts for such $p$ are wlog of the form $(U_i^+,\varphi_i)$,
where $U_i^+ = \{ x \in \overline{B}^n : x^i \geq 0 \}$, and

$$
\varphi_i (x) = (\pi_i \circ \sigma^{-1} )(x)= \frac{1}{|x|^2 + 1} (2x^1, \ldots, 2x^{i-1}, 2x^{i+1}, \ldots, |x|^2 - 1)
$$

(where $\pi_i$ is projection $R^{n+1} \to R^n$ that leaves out the $x^i$ coordinate; $\sigma$ is the stereographic projection.)

so i just need to show
$$
I_{R^n} \circ i \circ \varphi_i^{-1}=\varphi_i^{-1} = \sigma \circ \pi_i^{-1}
$$
is smooth. my issue is i'm having trouble computing $\sigma \circ \pi_i^{-1}$, which makes me think i'm approaching this question in the wrong way.

Comment: I assume you want to do this without the constant rank theorem. Idea: Wlog $p=(1,0,\cdots, 0).$ Then, with $f(\vec x)=\sum (x^i)^2-1$, you can use the chart $(f,x^2,\cdots,x^n)$

Comment: hi! it took me awhile but i got your hint (and was able to solve the problem); you essentially gave me the inverse of the projection map. thanks